# How to auto restart discord bot using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, raspberry-pi3, discord.py

Is there any way of making my discord bot auto-restart. What i mean is say if my wifi shut off and my bot went offline the code would detect the bot went offline it would attempt to restart the bot- if it failed it would wait 5 mins then try again. NOTE: The discord bot source code is running on python 3.6.5 on a raspberry pi 3

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I believe you need to reconnect during the disconnect event handler. It will keep trying til it succeeds

Comment: You might also want to try updating to the 1.0 branch.  [There's re-connection logic baked into the new `Client.connect`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#connection-improvements)

Comment: by 1.0 branch  do you  mean the rewrite   in which case i have it

Comment: Nick A what  disconnect event handler

Comment: searched it up but when i put in the bot token in bot.connect (TOKEN) it says takes 1 pontential argument but 2 were given. do . do bot.run then bot.connect?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done by creating seccond file:

```py
import os

while True:
    os.system("yourfilename.py")
    time.sleep(300)
```

this will run your bot 5 minutes after going offline every time that will happen